# Examples/Applications of equivalence relations in Computer Science

Tags: elementary-set-theory, computer-science, equivalence-relations

I am familiar with equivalence relation on a set, and its classical examples such as

> forming rational/real numbers, modular arithmetic, homotopy/homology, different forms of matrices etc.

But, I wanted to know an example/application of this in Computers, where certain problem on a set is reduced to equivalence classes on the set.

In the google search, I was unable to see examples *in computer science* (I saw many examples in Pure Mathematics branches, which I am not considering in above problem).

Comment: Well algebra has a _ton_ of applications in computer science, in algorithm design, cryptography, spectral graph theory, complexity theory, etc. And many of the algebraic constructions in these areas rest on quotient objects, which are special equivalence relations.

Comment: I agree; finite fields are highly used in computer science, and formation of finite fields involves equivalence relation (once or twice). But I was in search of a "concrete problem" in computer science, whose solution is done by equivalence relation (i.e. problem is reduced via equivalence relation, and it is solved by computer/programming).

Comment: Generating graphs is heavily based on the concept of equivalence relations. Graph isomorphism is an equivalence relation. We want only one representative for each equivalence class and reject all the others in our algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example the [Myhill-Nerode theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) uses equivalence classes on strings in an alphabet to determine whether a formal language is regular or not.

A language $L$ is a set of finite strings composed of characters from some alphabet $\Sigma$. We can say that two strings $x$ and $y$ are equivalent if for any string $z$, we have $x^\frown z\in L$ if and only if $y^\frown z\in L$ (here $^\frown$ denotes string concatenation). Let's use the symbol $x\equiv_L y$ to denote that $x$ and $y$ are equivalent.

Now the Myhill-Nerode theorem states that $L$ is a regular language if and only if there are only finitely many equivalence classes. In other words, if we can find an infinite set of strings $\{x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots\}$ such that $x_i\not\equiv_L x_j$ for every $i\neq j$, then $L$ is not a regular language, and vice versa.